# In history of algebra, who was the first to add one equation to another equation?

Tags: ho.history-overview

In history of algebra, who was the first to add one equation to another equation? Someone gave me the name of an Italian mathematician of Renaissance period, but I lost the email.

Comment: I don't think you can ever get a clear answer to a question like this, because the notion of equation was not very clearly defined before the invention of the equals sign. The mathematics of the past is very vague, unlike our clear contemporary definitions.

Comment: Didn't Euclid add two equations when he proved the theorem of Pythagoras? The square of the hypotenuse is the sum of two rectangles; each rectangle is equal in area to the square of one of the legs; adding those two equations, the square of the hypotenuse is equal to the sum of the squares of the legs.

Comment: Euclid's second axiom: if equals be added to equals, the sums are equal. What was the first time this axiom was used?

Comment: I think this question is better asked at [History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Already asked (and answered) in HSM; see the post [In history of algebra, who was the first to add one equation to another equation?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/7465/in-history-of-algebra-who-was-the-first-to-add-one-equation-to-another-equation).